# Object inside an array, passing an object to a PHP method

Tags: php, arrays, api, stdclass

I have a PHP application with a function that was built to expect information from an API call. However, I'm trying to use this function by passing in information that mimics the API data.

I struggle a bit with arrays and this seems to be an object within an array.

I can access the array that the api provides, so when I use the following code (`$triggers` is the array the api call returns):

`print("<pre>".print_r($triggers,true)."</pre>");`

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [triggerid] => 18186
            [status] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )
```

This is the beginning of the function:

```
function iterate_triggers($triggers){
    $trigger_id_values = array();
    foreach($triggers as $trigger) {
        //Necessary to show human readable status messages.
        $check_status = array(0=>"Up", 1=>"Down", 2=>"Degraded", 3=>"Maintenance");
        array_push ($trigger_id_values, [$trigger->triggerid, $trigger->value]);
```

So if I wanted to pass this function a `[triggerid] => 18186` and `[value] => 1` how would i do that?

Currently I'm trying:

```
iterate_triggers(array(0 => array("triggerid" => 18186,"status" => 0,"value" => 1,)));
```

but this gives me a **"Trying to get property of non-object"** error. Please be kind to me, I've done my best to research and structure this on my own to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if my comment would be of help but just want to point out that the error states it literally, you're trying to access an object when it's actually an array hence, `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: well it is helpful, but that is part of my problem. I'm not sure how to pass it to the function as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to cast the assoc array just to an object

In your case this would be

```
iterate_triggers(array(0 => (object)array("triggerid" => 18186,"status" => 0,"value" => 1,)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently creating and passing an array that contains an array, while your function expects an array of objects.

You should create your object beforehand, then construct your parameter array, and pass it to your function.

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->triggerid = 18186;
$obj->status = 0;
$obj->value = 1;
$arr = array($obj);
iterate_triggers($arr);
```

This [comment on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#107071), and the rest of that object documentation, may be useful to you.

> By far the easiest and correct way to instantiate an empty generic php object that you can then modify for whatever purpose you choose: `<?php $genericObject = new stdClass(); ?>`

The error message you are seeing with your own code is caused by `$trigger->triggerid` inside the function, when `$trigger` is an array instead of an object as the function expects. Object properties are accessed using `$someObject->propertyName` notation, while array elements are accessed using `$someArray['keyName']`